# how to click on a button on webpage for downloading a file whose link changes according to date using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to locate and download a file from a website using python and selenium, but i cannot locate it using xpath or id because every day i want to download the file of specific date .. the href tag consists of date so i tried using 'partial LINK text' but for some reason it gives me error while accesing yesterdays date.
P.S this is for a automation task

`<a href="default.aspx?d=Default/XCYs/ABX/v1/2024-02-21">2024-02-21</a>`

the above is the link to access with DATE changing everyday

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_date = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# Find an element by partial link text with yesterday's date
partial_link_text = yesterday_date
open_date_folder_yesterday = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, partial_link_text)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(open_date_folder_yesterday).perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the provided HTML, you could use a CSS selector,

```
a[href*='2024-02-21']
```

This just basically looks for an A tag where the href contains the desired date.

You can test this locator by navigating to the page in the browser, opening the dev tools using F12, and typing `$$("a[href*='2024-02-21']")` in the console. If it returns a single A tag, then you're good. If it returns more than one, you will likely have to add more of the URL in the locator, e.g.

```
a[href*='Default/XCYs/ABX/v1/2024-02-21']
```

or some variation of that.

Your updated code would look like

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_date = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

open_date_folder_yesterday = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"a[href*='{yesterday_date}']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(open_date_folder_yesterday).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using an extension to Selenium?

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

Not knowing the full details of your automation script, maybe something like this could solve your problem?

```py
from browserist import Browser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_date = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
download_link_xpath = f"//a[contains(@href, '{yesterday_date}')]"

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://example.com")
    browser.scroll.into_view_if_not_in_viewport(download_link_xpath)
    file_path = browser.click.download_and_get_file_path(download_link_xpath)
```

Notes:

- Maybe you don't need the `browser.scroll.into_view_if_not_in_viewport(download_link_xpath)` line of code, but this is similar to the `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(open_date_folder_yesterday).perform()` part.